# mod_rewrite - Does Apache caches .htaccess rules? (still follow rules even after deleting the .htaccess file)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I was doing some tests with mod_rewrite in my wamp environment.

I tested a simple rule that I put at the root of one of my websites and asked it to redirect any request ending with index.php to localhost (there is no sense to it, just wanted to check the rule)

It worked, but after, any change I'd made to my .htaccess file rule was not reflected.
After a while I just decided to delete the .htaccess... well it's still doing redirection! I just don't understand it. Does Apache cache the rules or something (restarting services trough wamp menu didn't change anything)

(Don't ask for the exact rule I used, since I deleted the file, I don't think it's relevant anyway)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.htaccess files are [processed each time a request comes through](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess#Advantages). It is possible that your browser cached the request being forwarded. Did you try it with [httpfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) or anything to see what the headers said?

Comment: Brilliant. I wonder, how on earth we didn't think of that. Thanks, of course your diagnose worked: just deleting browser's recent files was the solution. And moderators: yes, this forum is useful no matter it was a 2 years old answer.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried deleting the browser cache?

Comment: You are both right, I didn't think the browser would cache this. Thank you.

Comment: I think some browsers will cache it for a [301 response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) and a [302 under certain circumstances](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3).